# how to allow all task complete when using Task.WhenAll()?

Tags: c#

It seems like putting `Task.WhenAll()` in a `try-catch` block doesn't work. The code should upload all the images to ftp, but it seems like if one upload fails (for example, the image file is open in another process), the whole `uploadTasks` will stop, and `counts` is empty.

```
    private async Task Upload(Ftp ftpHost)
{
   var images = GetFileInfo() // will get a List<FileInfo>  

   var uploadTasks = images.Where(fi => fi.Exists).Select(async fi =>
   {
      var ret = await ftp.Upload(fi,_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
      fi.Delete();
      return ret;
   });
   IEnumerable<int> counts = new List<int>();
       try
       {
           counts = await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);
       }
       catch
       {
           //ignore to allow all upload complete 
       }

   var uploadedOrderFileByteCount = counts.Sum();
   var uploadedOrderFileCount = counts.Count();
}
```

Comment: You should be putting the `try/catch` around the `await` in your `async` lambda, so that one task failure doesn't bring them all down.

Comment: "the whole uploadTasks will stop, and counts is empty." --- are you sure it's stopped? The `counts` is empty because `await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks)` throws an exception, but all the tasks should be completed. See the last example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0yd65esw.aspx

Comment: I absolutely need put try catch in the lambda.and after doing that, the code worked as expected. How come I didn't try that before come here? "stop" wasn't correct word, it should be "complete".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that an empty catch block is often a bad idea (try to catch the exception which the ftp upload can throw especifically), if that's what you want to do, then the easiest way is to catch inside the operation itself, something similar to the code below.

```
var uploadTasks = images.Where(fi => fi.Exists).Select(async fi =>
{
    try
    {
        var ret = await ftp.Upload(fi,_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        fi.Delete();
        return ret;
    } catch {
        // again, please don't do this...
        return 0;
    }
});
IEnumerable<int> counts = new List<int>();
try
{
    counts = await Task.WhenAll(uploadTasks);
}
catch
{
    // Something bad happened, don't just ignore it
}
```